# Yup validation of a string value

Tags: forms, validation, yup

I try to validate input value if it contains a plain string value or not. And the problem is when user enters numbers YUP doesn't validate the result, shows an error and prevent fetching data from API. But when user enters string combined with numbers like 'ddw4848' YUP do validates value and approves API request.
My yup schema validation is below and it seems I'm stuck. Please help me what do I do wrong?

```js
const schema = yup.object({
  city: yup
    .string()
    .required("Looks like you forgot to type a city you are interested in")
    })
    .test("regex test", `Numbers can't be in a city name`, (val) => {
    const regExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    return regExp.test(val as string);
    })
    .test(
      "empty string test",
      "Looks like you forgot to type a city you are interested in",
      (val) => {
        return val.trim() !== "";
      }
    ),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line
const regExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;